# Difficult Definite Integral with inverse Cosh

Tags: integration

How can I solve this integral containing inverse cosh? Does it have any antiderivative?

$$ \int_b^r t^2 \operatorname{arccosh}(a/t) \sqrt{r^2 - t^2} d t$$

for $0< b< r< a$.

Comment: I have found the antiderivative and the integral if t^2 is replaced by t

Comment: I tried to fix the latex. Please do not copy paste mathwolfram commands here.

Comment: Only for $\{a,r\}\subseteq\{0,1\}$ apparently. And even then it looks hideous.